# Python best practices : pass globally known variable explicitly to a function or not?

Tags: python

I have a general question about Python best practices.
Tried googling for an answer, but didn't find anything relevant.
The question is : is it best practice to explicitly pass a globally known parameter to a function?

So, is this best practice?

```
a = 1

def add_one(a):
 b = a + 1
```

or this?

```
a = 1

def add_one():
 b = a + 1
```

Comment: If the function should use the variable in some way, then making it a forced argument will make it easier to debug in the future.

Comment: It's usually best practice to avoid global variables. The first does not even use the global `a` but shadows it.

Comment: Agreeing with @Jan - best not to use globals.  (FWIW; I’ve never found a use for them).  Rather, if you need a value to be accessed by several functions, consider making it a class attribute, (e.g. `self._a`).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer to expand on my comment regarding setting `a` as a class attribute, rather than using a `global`.

#### The Short Answer:

- Use `global`s with controlled caution; or the safe play ... just don't. There's *usually* a better way.

  - Ref 1: [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#global-variable-names)
  - Ref 2: [This interesting post on SO, emphasising the need for caution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19158339/6340496)
- Passing variables is OK
- Use a `class` at any (applicable) opportunity

#### Class Example:

Here is a simple, stripped down class structure with no frills. You'll notice the absence of any global variables, along with no passed variables.

This is **not** saying that passed variables are discouraged, they are useful, if not necessary. However, this **is** to show that globals are not needed, and there's usually a better way. For what it's worth ... (personally speaking, I've never seen the use for them in Python).

```
class Demo():
    """Class attribute demonstration class."""
    
    def __init__(self):
        """Demo class initialiser."""
        self._a = 73
        
    def add_one(self):
        """Add one to the `a` attribute."""
        self._a += 1
        
    def times_two(self):
        """Multiply the `a` attribute by two."""
        self._a *= 2
```

#### Use Case:

I'll be the first to point out that this example is all but useless in the real world due to 1) externally accessing a 'private' class attribute and 2) the continued updating of `_a`; this is only an example specific to your question.

Note that each call to a different function has a different, yet continued affect on `_a`; noting the variable (class attribute) is neither global, nor passed.

```
demo = Demo()
print(f'Value of _a: {demo._a}')
>>> Value of _a: 73

demo.add_one()
print(f'Value of _a plus one: {demo._a}')
>>> Value of _a plus one: 74    

demo.times_two()
print(f'Value of _a plus one, times two: {demo._a}')
>>> Value of _a plus one, times two: 148
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your elaborate answer.  This actually helps me  a lot in understanding !  Much appreciated.